# jQuery selectors - more elegant solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, web-scraping

Given the following HTML fragment:

```
<div class="word">
    <input type="text" name="A" />
    <input type="text" name="n" />
</div>
<div class="word">
    <input type="text" name="E" />
    <input type="text" name="x" />
    <input type="text" name="a" />
    <input type="text" name="m" />
    <input type="text" name="p" />
    <input type="text" name="l" />
    <input type="text" name="e" />  
</div>
```

I'd like to write a jQuery script that would concatenate all the `':text'` elements' names in a single string, while adding a space when reaching the end of a `'div.word'` element.

For example, given the HTML above, the result would be:

```
An Example
```

Using my (very) limited jQuery/javascript skills I managed to find a solution, but it involves dirty `for ... in` loops, so I'd rather not show it here :-).

I'd like to know what is a more elegant/idiomatic (and probably more concise) solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Here's a DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRukk/1/

```
var string = $('.word input').map(function() {
    var is_last = $(this).is(':last-child');
    return this.name + (is_last ? ' ' : '');
}).toArray().join('');
```

---

In modern browsers, you could do it without jQuery like this...

***Here's a DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRukk/4/

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.word input');

var string = [].map.call(inputs, function(el) {
    return el.name + (!el.nextElementSibling ? ' ' : '');
}).join('');
```

Comment: will that only take the `text` inputs?

Comment: @ajax333221: If the code in the question is reflective of the actual code, then yes, because that's the only kind of input there is. If not, then no, it would need to specified in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = [];
$('.word').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        result.push(this.name);
    });
    result.push(' ');
});
var answer = $.trim(result.join(''));
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DNWSm/

And, a slightly different way of doing it that is probably faster because it's probably less DOM searching:

```
var result = [];
var lastParent;
$('.word input').each(function() {
    // if starting a new parent, add a word separator
    if (lastParent && lastParent != this.parentNode) {
        result.push(' ');
    }
    result.push(this.name);
    lastParent = this.parentNode;
});
var answer = result.join('');
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bEBGQ/